# The type arguments for method IDialogStack.Wait<R>(ResumeAfter<R> resume) cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using an `IDialog` in my bot and one of my methods that is executed by the Bot Framework via `context.Wait()` had two arguments, as usual:

```
public async Task MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, 
                       IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
```

I want to add a third, optional argument to this method, which I will specify if I run this method directly from some place in my code (as opposed to when the Bot Framework runs it after `context.Wait()` and receiving a message from user).

So I change the method as follows:

```
public async Task MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, 
                       IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument, 
                       bool doNotShowPrompt = false)
```

Because of that, now all the `context.Wait` calls are shown as invalid:

[image: invalid context.wait]

That error disappears if I remove the third argument from the method declaration.

The message shown by Visual Studio is:

> The type arguments for method IDialogStack.Wait(ResumeAfter resume) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I assume that means I should call `context.Wait` as `context.Wait<SOMETHING>`, but I have no idea what to write instead of `SOMETHING`.

Comment: I don't thing adding an optional argument will make all the Wait to generate errors. Have you made any other changes? Can you post the code of the method MainScreenSelectionReceived.

Comment: @SethuBala the error disappears as soon as I remove the third argument from method declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an overload, rather than adding an optional argument. Your method signature now no longer satisfies the required delegate.

For example:

```
public async Task MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, 
                       IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument, bool doNotShowPrompt) 
{
    //Original code here
}

public async Task MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, 
                       IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument) 
{
    return await MainScreenSelectionReceived(context, argument, false);
}
```

Comment: But may I know why not as in the question? What is causing the issue there?

Comment: @SethuBala I'm not sure what you mean exactly, why not what in the question? The issue is because the method is expecting a delegate of a particular signature. Adding a parameter to `MainScreenSelectionRecieved` changes the signature, and thus it no longer satisfies the delegate signature.

Comment: @Rob Dang. You're right. I was doing kind of the reverse of that, an overload for calling that method with a non-default value.

Comment: To be more clear I am curious why not change the signature of the original method itself? What is the root cause of the error on Wait?

Comment: @SethuBala `Wait` is asking for a method which takes a context and an argument. OP is now passing it a method which takes a context, an argument, and a 'doNotShowPrompt'. Thus, it's invalid.

Comment: Yeah, now I understood. Actually to be frank, it was my later realization of the method signature. Thanks @Rob

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the way the delegate that is being passed to `context.Wait()` is declared:

```
public delegate Task ResumeAfter<in T>(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<T> result);
```

You can see that this method is expecting to be passed a delegate with the exact signature `MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)`.

You can either create an overloaded method that gets called directly:

```
MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
     => MainScreenSelectionReceived(context, argument, false);

MainScreenSelectionReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument,
bool doNotShowPrompt)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

**Or** pass a lambda expression to the `context.Wait()` method:

```
context.Wait((c, a) => MainScreenSelectionReceived(c, a, false));
```